# In HLSL, how do I set a float to NaN?

Tags: unity-game-engine, directx, hlsl

I have a function which returns a float3 if certain conditions are met, but I want to return float3(nan, nan, nan) if these conditions aren't met. Infinities should do the same job.

Comment: have you tried 0/0 or sqrt(-1)?

Comment: 0/0 doesn't compile and sqrt(-1) doesn't seem to work (I might be using it incorrectly, though)

Comment: @JimmyDiddler Did you find an answer to this question? If an answer below is helpful, consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep points to comment on @Ruzihm's answer. Just wanted to mention that the custom IsNaN method did the trick for me.  Thanks!

In my case, I'm porting a math utility I wrote in C# to a .cginc file to use in compute shaders. I also use a NaN constant as a return value in some of my methods as an early out.

Here's a simple example to illustrate the point:

**HLSL**

```
#pragma kernel CSMain
#pragma warning( disable: 4008 )

const static float NaN = 0.0f / 0.0f;

RWStructuredBuffer<float3> _OutBuffer;

bool IsNaN(float x)
{
  return !(x < 0.0f || x > 0.0f || x == 0.0f);
}

[numthreads(1, 1, 1)]
void CSMain(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
  if (IsNaN(NaN))
  {
    _OutBuffer[0] = float3(NaN, NaN, NaN);
  }
  else
  {
    _OutBuffer[0] = float3(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
  }
}
```

Unity will throw a warning about the division by zero. Per the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-appendix-pre-pragma-warning) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/hlsl-errors-and-warnings) I suppressed the warning with the second `#pragma` directive.

**C#**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class HlslNan: MonoBehaviour
{
  public ComputeShader cShader;

  void Start()
  {
    var outData = new Vector3[1];
    var outBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(1, sizeof(float) * 3);
    outBuffer.SetData(outData);

    cShader.SetBuffer(0, "_OutBuffer", outBuffer);
    cShader.Dispatch(0, 1, 1, 1);

    outBuffer.GetData(outData);

    Debug.Log(outData[0]); // logs (NaN, NaN, NaN), as expected.

    outBuffer.Release();
    outBuffer.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [HLSL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d10/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-resources-float-rules) on floats, 0/0 in floating point math will produce a NaN, so you can just do :

```
float nan = 0. / 0.;
```

You can confirm this works if you use a nan checker that doesn't get optimized away:

```
Shader "Custom/NaNChecker" {
    Properties{
    }
    SubShader{
        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert_img
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            float IsNaN(float x) {
                return (x < 0. || x > 0. || x == 0.) ? 0. : 1.;
            }

            // Displays Red
            float4 frag(v2f_img i) : COLOR {
                return float4(IsNaN(0. / 0.), 0, 0, 1);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`float3` in Unity doesn't have a `NaN` property. You'll either need to establish your own "special value" for this (not recommended) or wrap the function's return type with another value, eg:

```
public struct FunctionOperationResult
{
   public float3 Response {get; set;}
   public bool Result {get; set;}
}
```

And set `Result` to false if the operation failed.

Comment: This question is about [tag:hlsl], not [tag:c#]

Comment: @Ruzihm the core idea would stay the same though: Use a struct with a `float3` and a `bool` and use the bool to check if it is valid or not .. probably something like `struct float3Result { float3 value; bool valid; };`

Comment: I definitely *could* do that but it seems so clunky when (at least as I understand it), NaN is meant to be part of a standard FP32 implementation. Also minimising the amount of data being sloshed about would be nice - especially since this is a performance-critical function.